# Does top bar work without JavaScript in Zurb Foundation 5?

Tags: javascript, css, html, zurb-foundation

I'm currently evaluating Zurb Foundation and tried to create a top bar with a menu. Somehow the links in my dropdown menus didn't work so I went basic:

I downloaded the zip, took their index.html and replaced the contents with the example from the [top bar documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html). After removing everything that's unnecessary for the example, I got this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
      <section class="top-bar-section">
        <ul class="right">
          <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#">Go to</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </nav>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works: the menu opens (on hover) and I can click the links. But if I remove the JavaScript initialization

```
$(document).foundation();
```

the menu still opens (but now only after a click and not a hover) and when I hover the menu entries, the status bar shows the appropriate links but clicking on them doesn't do anything.

I thought we were over that that we need JavaScript for the most basic things. I mean we can even do animations without JavaScript nowadays but here I can't even open a link? Am I doing something wrong or is this really intended behavior? As a NoScript user this would be a no go for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. These features in ZURB Foundation don't work without JavaScript. In addition, mobile menu doesn't work without JavaScript correctly too so definitely you need JavaScript to get Top Bar work properly.

By the way, you can see JS icon in [Foundation documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs) next to every Foundation item which need JavaScript to work properly - Top Bar has it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I wasn't sure what "JS" exactly referred to. That's a bummer. I guess that puts the final nail in the coffin. I had a difficult time with it anyway. Thanks! I'll look for something else.